# creating a gauze metric from a python list

Tags: python, metrics, prometheus

Working on a python list. Below is sample

```
result=[{'time': '00:00'}, {'app': 'dgn'}, {'avg': '7717'}, {'time': '00:00'}, {'app': 'pds'}, {'avg': '75.40223463687151'}]
```

I'm creating a gauge metric from above data. Tried the following to yield metric from above data:

```
class EventMetricCollector(object):
def avg_response_time_metric(self):


    metric = GaugeMetricFamily(
        'avg_response_time_ms',
        'average response time',
        labels=["time","app","avg"])

    for time, app, avg in result:
        metric.add_metric([time],[app],[avg])

    return metric

def collect(self):
    yield self_avg_response_time_metric()
```

However, I'm getting this error while running

```
for time, app, avg in result:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

My expected output:

```
avg_response_time_metric{time="0",app=:"dgn",avg="7717"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is expecting three values to unpack from list, but only one is unpacked.

You need to `zip()` through list. Try replacing to this `for` loop:

```
for time, app, avg in zip(result[::3], result[1::3], result[2::3]):
```

This `zip`s through adjacent three elements of list simultaneously.

Comment: now getting error as   "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'"

Comment: Sorry, could not help you on that unless you share whole code.

Comment: i am using result as                                                                         
                                                                                                                       
 result=[{'time': '00:00'}, {'app': 'dcg'}, {'avg': '7717'}, {'time': '00:00'}, {'app': 'rtd'}, {'avg': '75.40223463687151'}, {'time': '00:00'}, {'app': 'rtd'}, {'avg': '1481.5555555555557'}, {'time': '00:00'}, {'app': 'slb'}, {'time': '01:00'}, {'app': 'rtd'}, {'avg': '36.4765625'}]      having key value pair inside a list.

Comment: also posted whole code. excluded only  import library/module sections

Answer (score 0):

Combining Alex's suggestion with your code snippet:

```
class EventMetricCollector(object):
   def avg_response_time_metric(self):

       metric = GaugeMetricFamily(
           'avg_response_time_ms',
           'average response time',
           labels=["time","app","avg"])

       for time, app, avg in zip(result[::3], result[1::3], result[2::3]):
           metric.add_metric([time],[app],[avg])

       return metric

    def collect(self):
      yield self_avg_response_time_metric()
```